# Different interface for firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Maybe this is a weird question, but why did my firebase realtime database changed the interface? Yesterday i still using the same old interface for realtime database, but today the interface changed and become abit laggy. I try searched on internet about this issue but dont have any answers.

Previous database:

[image: Previous]

Current database interface:

[image: Current]

Does anyone know the caused of this issue? and how to solve it? I want to revert back to previous interface

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

We recently updated the user interface for the Realtime Database in the Firebase console. There is no way to revert it back to the old interface, nor should that be needed. If you find that certain features are missing or bugs have been introduced in the new user interface, please file a [file a bug report or feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) or on the [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk) mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure the UI in Firebase console. If you have any feedback on the new interface then can share that with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).